# JWplayer caption windows color opacity not working

Tags: ios, swift, jwplayer

I tried to change Caption background color depends upon caption text length.I'm also try to reduce window color opacity but can't work.

Already tried method:
Captions Styling -> window Colour opacity property used
SDK version:2.9.1 and 3.3.0+

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#captions
Didn't take opacity property